# git move repository to another repository as a directory

Tags: git, github

How do I move repository (old_rep) to another repository (new_rep) as a directory without loosing the history and files for repositories?

Here is what I tried from other stack questions. I have files in new_repo like directories, .txt, .sql files with history. When I run the codes below, looks like the --mirror is replacing everything from old_rep into new_rep.

```
mkdir foo
cd foo 

git clone --bare ssh://git@test.test.test/test/old_rep.git

cd old_rep.git 
git clone --bare ssh://git@test.test.test/test/new_rep.git

cd ..
rm -rf old_rep.git
```

Comment: If you go into old_rep.git, do some operation, cd .. and rm -Rf old_rep.git, did you not just delete everything?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you want to move all the content from `old_repo` into the directory `dir1` of `new_repo`:

1. In `old_repo` create `dir1`, move all the files and directories from the working directory into `dir1` and commit.

   That's all with `old_repo`. The other steps below happen in `new_repo`.
2. In `new_repo` use `git remote add old_repo <path-to-old-repo>` to add the old repo as a remote for the new repo. Replace `<path-to-old-repo>` with the actual path (full or relative) of the old repository. I assume you have both repositories on the local computer.
3. Make sure there are not uncommitted changes. If there are then commit them on a branch or stash them.
4. Run `git fetch old_repo` to get the commits from the old repo into the new repo. Assuming you already have checked out the branch where you want to import the code from `old_repo`, run `git merge old_repo/master`. Replace `master` with the actual branch from `old_repo` you want to import.
5. Check that everything looks good in `new_repo` and you have all the files from `old_repo` and their history.
6. Cleanup. Only after you double-checked step 5, run `git remote remove old_repo` to unlink the repos and then, if you are sure you don't need anything from `old_repo`, you can remove the directory where `old_repo` is located. I would do the removal after some time (1-2 weeks), just to make sure I don't lose anything.
7. That's all.

Comment: Note that for some Git versions, the merge will need the `--allow-unrelated-histories` flag

Answer (score 1):

This is something I found to be a lot simpler. The answer below assumes like me you don't care too much for this old repo as much as I used to because it's old or the new repo is just storage for old repos. Which is why I don't mind doing it this way.

1. Clone the old repo(s) for move on to your local machine
2. Make new destination repo from your local machine or git clone from an existing repo
3. Copy and Paste all folders and files from old repo(s) into destination repo folder on your machine
4. `git add .` then `git commit` and then `git push`
5. Delete Old Repo

Comment: The OP said they wanted to preserve all commit history.